# You can’t remove the following public properties because the component is part of a managed package

Tags: lightning-web-components, vs-code

I am trying to push a JS file in a LWC Component and am unable to do so with this error

lwc/boatMap/boatMap.js-meta.xml: You can’t remove the following public properties: boatId, because the component is part of a managed package.
Below is my JS code.

```
// import BOATMC from the message channel
import { LightningElement,wire,api,track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { APPLICATION_SCOPE,subscribe,MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
import BOATMC from '@salesforce/messageChannel/BoatMessageChannel__c';
// Declare the const LONGITUDE_FIELD for the boat's Longitude__s
// Declare the const LATITUDE_FIELD for the boat's Latitude
// Declare the const BOAT_FIELDS as a list of [LONGITUDE_FIELD, LATITUDE_FIELD];
const LONGITUDE_FIELD = 'Boat__c.Geolocation__Longitude__s';
const LATITUDE_FIELD = 'Boat__c.Geolocation__Latitude__s';
const BOAT_FIELDS = [LONGITUDE_FIELD, LATITUDE_FIELD];
export default class BoatMap extends LightningElement {
  // private
  subscription = null;
  boatId;
  // Getter and Setter to allow for logic to run on recordId change
  // this getter must be public
  @api get recordId() {
    return this.boatId;
  }
  set recordId(value) {
    this.setAttribute('boatId', value);
    this.boatId = value;
  }
  //public
  error = undefined;
  @track mapMarkers = [];
  // Initialize messageContext for Message Service
  @wire(MessageContext)
    messageContext;
  // Getting record's location to construct map markers using recordId
  // Wire the getRecord method using ('$boatId')
  @wire(getRecord,{recordId:'$boatId',fields:BOAT_FIELDS})
  wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
    // Error handling
    if (data) {
      this.error = undefined;
      const longitude = data.fields.Geolocation__Longitude__s.value;
      const latitude = data.fields.Geolocation__Latitude__s.value;
      this.updateMap(longitude, latitude);
    } else if (error) {
      this.error = error;
      this.boatId = undefined;
      this.mapMarkers = [];
    }
  }
  // Runs when component is connected, subscribes to BoatMC
  connectedCallback() {
    // recordId is populated on Record Pages, and this component
    // should not update when this component is on a record page.
    if (this.subscription || this.recordId) {
      return;  
    }
    
    if(!this.subscription){
      this.subscription = subscribe(
        this.messageContext,
        BOATMC,
        (message) => {this.boatId = message.recordId},
        { scope: APPLICATION_SCOPE }
      ); 
    }
    // Subscribe to the message channel to retrieve the recordID and assign it to boatId.
  }
  // Creates the map markers array with the current boat's location for the map.
  updateMap(Longitude, Latitude) {
    this.mapMarkers = [{
      location : {
        latitude : Latitude,
        longitude : Longitude
      }
    }];
  }
  // Getter method for displaying the map component, or a helper method.
  get showMap() {
    return this.mapMarkers.length > 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is happening to us as well. We have a Managed-Released package already. We added some new properties in the dev org, but never packaged them. Nevertheless, we cannot remove them from the local environment now. REALLY frustrating. Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Have u found a solution for this?

Comment: @VarunC with second generation package you can just reset ancestry

Comment: My package is 1st gen. there is currently no path to migrate to 2gp as well.

Comment: This is tragic if you were not aware of this behavior before. Saw this idea which should be a known issue IMO: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000PeNNQA0

Answer (score 0):

Remove the component from your package and then install it again.  That should do it

Answer (score 0):

Making boatId as a public property would fix this. Add @api annotation to boatId.
`@api boatId;`

Answer (score 0):

I think the only option is to restore the @api decorator

```
export default class BoatMap extends LightningElement {
  // private
  subscription = null;
  @api
  boatId;
```